# Is Yudhishtira's justification of polyandry in accordance with dharma?

Tags: dharma, pandavas, yudhisthira, draupadi, polyandry

In the Mahabharata, Yudhishthira [justifies](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01199.htm) his polyandrous relationship with Draupadi with two reasons: it has historic precedent, and because his mother ordered the Pandavas to share Draupadi:

> "Yudhishthira then spoke, saying, 'My tongue never uttereth an untruth and my heart never inclineth to what is sinful. When my heart approveth of it, it can never be sinful. I have heard in the Purana that a lady of name Jatila, the foremost of all virtuous women belonging to the race of Gotama had married seven Rishis. So also an ascetic's daughter, born of a tree, had in former times united herself in marriage with ten brothers all bearing the same name of Prachetas and who were all of souls exalted by asceticism. O foremost of all that are acquainted with the rules of morality, it is said that obedience to superior is ever meritorious. Amongst all superiors, it is well-known that the mother is the foremost. Even she hath commanded us to enjoy Draupadi as we do anything obtained as alms. It is for this, O best of Brahmanas, that I regard the (proposed) act as virtuous.'

But polyandry is a non-Vedic practice:

> Aitareya Brahmana III. 3. - Therefore, there are several wives for one
> man, but not several husbands for a woman simultaneously

In the MB section linked above, even king Drupada says that polyandry is non-Vedic:

> The practice is sinful in my opinion, being opposed to both usage and the Vedas. O best of Brahmanas, nowhere have I seen many men having one wife. The illustrious ones also of former ages never had such a usage amongst them.

Now, Drupada is clearly wrong about there being no historic precedent, but he is correct that polyandry is apparently non-Vedic.

Now that there is a Vedic prohibition of polyandry, can anything override it? Consider this verse from the Manusmriti:

> 2.6 - The entire Veda is the root-source of Dharma, as well as the practices found in Smriti,
> the traditional practices of Vaidikas (AcAra), and their self-satisfaction.

Shruti (Veda) takes precedence over Smriti, which takes precedence over AcAra, which takes precedence over one's own opinion. So how can one's mother or any authority order a non-Vedic practice? If my father tells me to murder someone, then I doubt that that act becomes dharma.

Moreover, the Mimamsakas make it clear that traditional or regional customs only have authority as long as they don't conflict with the Vedas.

The Apastamba Dharma Sutra [also says](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/apastamba__dharma_grihya_sutras.pdf):

> Ācārya adhīnaḥ syād anyatra patanīyebhyaḥ

> He shall obey his teacher, except [when ordered to commit] sins which cause loss of caste.

From all this, I don't see how Yudhishthira's justification of polyandry is valid, unless it is the case that Smriti, AcAra, and sAdhutuSTi are on the same level as the Vedas.

Comment: I think not very part of the Vedas is eternal and authoritative. So laws can change with time.

Comment: @DarkKnight Correct, look at this: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/43471/11726

Comment: I think the answer is **NO**, Because no one can controdict the Vedas. "*The Puranas and other religious scriptures are all denoted by the word "Smriti". And their authority goes so far as they follow the Vedas and do not contradict them*". [By ramakrishna](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_6/writings_prose_and_poems/hinduism_and_shri_ramakrishna.htm). So Yudhishthira controdicts the Vedas. He is wrong.

Comment: What comes before the "therefore?" That's an incomplete idea. It's possible it only applies to some cases.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa "What comes before the 'therefore'" - Some kind of symbolic idea/explanation.

Comment: @Ikshvaku What if it qualifies it for a situation? e.g. When the X were victorious and killed many men of the enemy (thus the ratio made practical sense).

Comment: The Vedas available to us are not the complete ones.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Correct, but we don't know what the other Vedas say

Comment: Yudhishthira himself later indirectly confirmed that polyandry is sinful by staking draupadi in dice game. All pandavas including Yudhishthira were polygamists. Yudhishthira could have staked other wives instead of draupadi but he chose to stake polyandrous draupadi FIRST.

Comment: @ArvindC You've got to be kidding me. Draupadi is considered a dharma-patni, a very righteous woman. He didn't stake her because she's sinful, he staked her because she was a very important figure and his primary wife/queen.

Comment: @Ikshvaku true... she was dharma-patni but my point is what was her position in Yudhishthira's mind ? we don't know exactly how mahabharata dice game worked but generally more important ones are staked last, so if draupadi was "most important" in his mind he would have staked other wives first and then at last draupadi just like the stakes started from  increasing age/importance of brothers twins > arjuna > bhima > Yudhistira

Answer (score 1):

As per mahAbhArata, polyandry was sinful:

> *mahAbhArata 1.160.36*
>
> *O revered sir, abandoning me thou mayest obtain another wife. By her thou mayest again acquire religious merit. There is no sin in this.
> For a man polygamy is an act of merit, but **for a woman it is very
> sinful to betake herself to a second husband after the first**.*
>
> *mahAbhArata 14.80.12-18*
>
> *O blessed lady, **polygamy is not fault with men**. **Women only incur fault by taking more than one husband**.*

> In case of polyandry of draupadi in Adi parva CLXLVIII, yudhiShThira was not justifying polyandry a sinless practice  as for him it was a choice  between "more
> sinful v/s less sinful"  i.e.
> yudhiShThira was of the opinion that disobeying mother's word was more
> sinful than polyandry. Note that draupada, dhrishtadyumna etc. were
> countering it the other way round i.e. polyandry more sinful than
> disobeying mother's word.

In mahAbhArata  Adi parva CLXLVII, draupada says that he has not heard of such a practice -

> *'Drupada answered, 'O scion of Kuru's race, it hath been directed that one man may have many wives. But it hath never been heard that
> one woman may have many husbands!*

Now because an elderly person like draupada hasn't heard of such a practice, yudhiShThira in response points out that he is not the first one to commit such a (sinful) act - a lady of name Jatila  and an ascetic's daughter, born of a tree have already done it in past.

Eventually draupada gives his consent in Adi parva section CC only with a disclaimer that he is not a party to the sin implying that everyone including yudhiShThira was in agreement that polyandry was sinful but they were doing it only because it was unavoidable due to  destiny and kuntI's words:

> *The knot of **destiny** cannot be untied. Nothing in this world is the result of our own acts. That which had been appointed by us in view of
> securing one only bridegroom hath now terminated in favour of many. As
> Krishna (in a former life) had repeatedly said, 'O, give me a
> husband!' the great god himself even gave her the boon she had asked.
> The god himself knows the right or wrong of this. **As regards myself,
> when Sankara hath ordained so, right or wrong, no sin can attach to
> me**.*

Answer (score -2):

I doubt the Vedas really are against polyandry. That quote might be out of context. For example, the [Maruts, who seem to be virtuous,, confirmed in a later verse, are all husbands of the Earth](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv05058.htm). While some may think that is a metaphor, the Earth has literal children like Naraka elsewhere, and I don't see what the metaphor could be in context.

> Even Earth hath spread herself wide at their coming, and they (probably Maruts) **as husbands have with power impregned her**.
>
> ...
>
> 8 Ho! Maruts, Heroes, **skilled in Law**, immortal, be gracious unto us, ye rich in treasures,

Additionally, the Aitareya Brahmana quote is not about humans, or any race for that matter. It is referring to the [marriage between the Rig Veda and Sama Veda](https://archive.org/stream/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft/aitareyabrahmana04hauguoft_djvu.txt). The reason it says that is Sama Veda has three wives and Rig Veda has one husband. This has no relevance on anyone else. This is like saying one man has three bedrooms because he has three wives, therefore everyone must have three wives. Thus, there is no conflicting Vedic verse to counteract (as if that makes sense if the Vedas are true) the one I gave above.

> First there existed the Rik and the Saman (separate from one an-
> other) ; sd was the Rik, and the name amai?i.was the Saman. Sd, which was
> Rik, said to the Saman, '* Let us copulate for begetting children." The
> Saman answered, " No ; for my greatness exceeds (yours •." (Thereupon)
> the Rik became two ; both spoke (to the Saman to the same effect); but
> [ 197 j it did not comply with their request. The Rik became three
> (divided into three) ; all three spoke (to the Saman to the same effect).
> Thus the Saman joined the three Riehas. Thence the Sama singers use
> for their chant three Richas,^^ (that is) they perform their work of chanting
>
> with three Richas, (This is so also in worldly affairs.) For one man
> has manj^ wives (represented by the Richas), but one wife has not many
> husbands at the same time. From sd and avialt, having joined, sama was
> produced. Thence it is called sdman.^ He who has such a knowledge
> becomes sdman, i.e., equal, equitous. He who exists and attains to the
> highest rank, is a sdman, whilst they use the word asdmanya, i.e.,
> inequitous, partial, as a term of reproach.

As a side note, I think all subsequent marriages after the first (even if divorced) have to at best be Gandharva weddings, but those are never discouraged except relatively to better versions.

---

By the way, the only reason humans don't tend to use polyandry is our outdated reproduction method using internal wombs. This causes suspicion of parentage and a bunch of other problems. Other races (and future humans) will not have internal wombs (the only mentions of other races with internal wombs are in boon stories, which [I don't believe are real](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50030/21895)). Without our terrible reproductive system, there is no real reason again polyandry for society (I don't think the reasons are big enough for all cases). In fact we are already evolving past this miserable condition ([https://www.thelancet.com/journals/langlo/article/PIIS2214-109X(18)30451-0/fulltext#:~:text=Of%20the%2038%20countries%20with,12%C3%970](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/langlo/article/PIIS2214-109X(18)30451-0/fulltext#:%7E:text=Of%20the%2038%20countries%20with,12%C3%970))%20in%202014.)

Comment: English translations of Sanskrit scriptures are generally a poor reflection of truth or author's intentions.

Comment: @mar How would you even get this wrong? It's not like these words together are easily confused with anything else.

Comment: @mar I'm all for not trusting quotes or translations, but that requires a plausible scenario for them to get it wrong.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa What does the Marut verse have to do with whether polyandry is sinful for humans or not? The Aitareya Brahmana verse, regardless of whatever reason or dumb analogy/explanation it gives, explicitly prohibits polyandry. Also, if people do polyandry, they won't know who the father is, so there are impractical issues aside from scriptural prohibitions.

Comment: @Ikshvaku The Aitareya Brahmana verse is not prohibiting polyandry, it is explaining something using the polygamous and non polyandrous relationship of Rig Veda and Sama Veda. It is not prohibiting anything.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Hinduism details the bad traits of even the Indras and Prajapatis. Do you really think it would leave out the Maruts' bad deeds for no reason? The Maruts seem genuinely virtuous, without cheating. Also it is in the middle of praising them and they are called skilled in law later.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Although to be fair, the Maruts might just be that good because of how young they are (for Devas), so they have not had time to turn evil. Although that is irrelevant to the point at hand.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa "The Aitareya Brahmana verse is not prohibiting polyandry" - It is according to the followers of the aitareya brahmana and Bharuci, who was a 7th century commentator of the Manusmriti. He cites his Brahmana verse in the section of the Manusmriti which prohibits polyandry and permits polygamy. Also, if we go by the purva mimamsa theory of interpretation, then this verse is a *viddhi*, while the Rig and Sama analogy is an *atharvada*, and the Vedas contain many supporting atharvadas that *might not make any logical sense*, yet the supported viddhi is still accepted.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa On the other hand, the Marut verse you cited is a Samhita *mantra*, which just praises the Maruts, but it doesn't *enjoin* any dharma or karma. Mantras *do not have the power to enjoin anything*, since all they do is praise. Also, the Marut verse doesn't even say that the Maruts all married the Earth. It says they "impregnated the Earth", which means something like they put their mark on planet Earth. You can impregnate without marrying. How can you anyway marry planet Earth? What does that even mean?

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa The Aitareya Brahmana verse does in fact literally prohibit polyandry, because look at the wording: "*Therefore*, there are several wives for one man, but not several husbands for a woman simultaneously". It uses words like man, woman, husband, and wife, which are all HUMAN relationships and appellations. The *atharvada* is the Rk and Saman analogy, which *may not make sense*, but it is what it is. Aside from all this, you're still ignoring Vyasa's statement in the Mahabharata that, "this practice is against usage and the Vedas", as well as countless smriti references.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Bhudevi (Earth) is the wife of Vishnu, NOT the Maruts. So this verse has another meaning. There is not a single shred of evidence from the Vedas or elsewhere that polyandry is acceptable in Hinduism. All you can do is cherry pick, split hairs, and find vague references like you are doing now, but it's still now match to the OCEAN of smriti and shruti.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa You're problem is that you already have a deep-seated bias/presupposition into thinking that the Vedas support polyandry, for whatever reason you acquired that presupposition, maybe you were raised into thinking that. This is why you start your answer by saying, "I doubt the Vedas really are against polyandry."  when you are presented with a Vedic verse that apparently shows that the Vedas are against polyandry. That is where you are coming from, and every single thing after that is interpreted on that supposition, and once I've shown you an OCEAN of contrary evidence....

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa You are UNABLE to accept that evidence and are COPING. You can't even give a proper interpretation of the Aitareya Brahmana verse. All you said is, "it is explaining something", well, WHAT is it explaining? You can only determine that it's explaining "something"...., but cannot provide further details.

Comment: @Ikshvaku 1. I'm sure there are conclusions based on the Vedas you disagree with. 2. It says husbands and why would you call out their sin in the middle of praising them? 3. Your wording only works out of context. For makes more sense. Are you sure the person you heard it from translated the whole thing or just this verse out of context?

Comment: @Ikshvaku "9 Be to us easy of approach, even as a father to his son:" Does that mean Krshna/Shiva sinned for being away from their children. Same "logic." https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01001.htm

Comment: @Ikshvaku I literally just had to look at the first verse in the Veda to come up with an equally, clearly not what it means, meaning out of context.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa I just checked sayana's commentary on the Marut verse, and he said the "impregnation" by the maruts is that they brought water to the Earth to fill up the oceans, hence the language. Also it says "iva", which means *like* husbands. So the meaning would be "the maruts filled the earth with water, just as husbands impregnate their wives". The Maruts are storm gods.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Well, what do you think the Aitareya verse means? As I said, the meaning I gave is advocated by the followers of the Aitareya shakha, as well as Bharuci, so the translation is correct. The atharvada may be illogical, but it is what it is.

Comment: @Ikshvaku "The waters are disturbed" implies there was water before. Also, how does adding an ocean count as impregnating? Also, a story like this really needs a source.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Followers of Aitareya shakha are presumable in different languages. How do you know this wasn't a Chinese whispers situation>?

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Well, transmission of vedas is very reliable. But actually people are also starting to not understand the vedic language, and so translations vary wildly from one scholar to another, so that's why smriti was created. In reality, we just follow the achara (tradition) of elders.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa And yes, as you said, there are conclusions based on Vedas I don't agree with, and I've been called out as a "heretic" many times in strong ways. Very sad.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa I was a reading a verse that reminded me of what you said. You said the Vedas would not call out Maruts for a sin in the middle of praising them, but there is a verse from the Shatapatha Brahmana where Indra is praised as the *lover of Ahalya*, referencing the story where he did adultery with a Brahmin's wife: "3:3:4:18. 'Come, O Indra!' Indra is the deity of the sacrifice: therefore he says, 'Come, O Indra!' 'Come, O lord of the bay steeds! Ram of Medhâtithi! Wife of Vrishanasva! Bestriding buffalo! Lover of Ahalyâ!' Thereby he wishes him joy in those affairs of his."

Comment: And we can't obviously interpret this verse to mean that adultery is not sinful just because Indra is praised as an adulterer.